# YouTube "resume where you left off " doesn't work in Ubuntu in Chrome or in Firefox

Tags: windows, google-chrome, youtube, google

I noticed that Windows PCs have this cool feature to resume YouTube videos where you left off.

There is also a progress bar at the bottom of a video that shows how much you have watched of a video.

This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu, in Chrome or in Firefox

## edit 1 :

using latest version of chrome and firefox namely :

chrome : Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)

firefox : 50.1.0

ubuntu version 16.04LTS

## edit 2 :

I have also tried chrome dev Version 57.0.2970.0 dev (64-bit)
still not work

I have also noticed that the `audio search` from `address bar` not working !

Comment: Did you disable or block cookies in Crrome/Firefox?

Comment: Generally with this sort of question, it would be useful if you told which version of Ubuntu you are using, which versions of Firefox and Chrome you tried, and where you installed them from (did you install them from the Ubuntu repositories, or did you download them from the Mozilla and Google websites?). The resume feature on YouTube is working for me on Firefox (though I generally find it annoying), so if you could edit your question to include the above info it might help people understand why it is not working in your specific situation.

Comment: versions are added ,
and I have installed them from their official sites respectively .

Comment: @blendenzo , I know it might be annoying however its more annoying that I can't get it to work !

Answer (score 2):

Works for me with current repository version of SeaMonkey (a reskinned Firefox with built-in mail client and HTML editor), but it depends on being logged into your Google (or YouTube) account.  If you're not logged into YouTube, they won't store anything.

Comment: Seamonkey is **not** reskinned Firefox :)